# What is this billing software?

Tags: untagged

Can anyone tell what billing software they're using?

http://www.firehost.com/secure-hosting/configure

Answer (score 2):

Yeah - they can. No one else is likely to be able to.

Answer (score 1):

"billing software"?  Looks like they've built a custom order form, kind of like what 99% of online service providers do.